# Activar Virtualización Intel 4510U para Docker

Tags: windows, docker, virtualbox

Se dispone de un portátil con un i7 4510U y Windows 10 Home 64 Bits.

Si se activa en la Bios la virtualizacion, la aplicación de intel para la identificación de procesadores, indica que está desactivada. En cambio si en Bios se pone a disable, la aplicación indica que si está activa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema viene al ejecutar DOCKER QUICKSTART que da el siguiente error, estén a NO o SI las opciones de la captura.

> Running pre-create checks... Error with pre-create check: "This
>   computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is
>   mandatory" Looks like something went wrong in step ´Checking if
>   machine default exists´... Press any key to continue...

Tambien se han seguido los pasos indicados en https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/412#issuecomment-288118331 He desactivado dentro de Windows Defender la directiva de protección de la virtualización, pero sigue todo igual.

**SOLUCIÓN:**

run below command in command prompt with admin mode:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUCIÓN:**

run below command in command prompt with admin mode:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```